# Finite product of algebras of finite type

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.
Let $B, C$ be $A$-algebras of finite type.
Is $B \times C$ an $A$-algebra of finite type?

Comment: Given (finite) sets of generators for $B$ and $C$, you should be able to construct a (finite) set of generators for $B \times C$.

Comment: @PaulZ I'm expecting someone will post the proof. Regards,

Comment: To the downvoters, what's wrong with question?

Comment: What's wrong with it is it looks like a homework question. And if it is, it's an easy one; my comment is all the hint a student should need.

Comment: @Paul Z: Could you please post your "easy" choice of generators for $B\times C$ ?

Comment: @PaulZ It is not homework.

Comment: In my opinion, downvoting a question just because it is easy to answer is *thoughtless*.
For example, see Georges's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to show that $B = A [x_1, \ldots, x_n] \times A [y_1, \ldots, y_m]$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra. The elements of are pairs $(f, g)$ where $f \in A [x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and $g \in A [y_1, \ldots, y_m]$. But $(f, g) = (f, 0) + (0, g)$, and $f$ and $g$ are sums of monomials, so we see that $B$ is generated by $\{ (1, 0), (x_1, 0), \ldots, (x_n, 0), (0, 1), (0, y_1), \ldots, (0, y_m) \}$.

Comment: Dear Zhen, your answer is perfect:+1. I was wondering: what is the smallest number of algebra generators for your $B$? My answer is $n+m-+1$: I take all your generators except $(0,1)$, since $(0,1)=(1,1)-(1,0)$. Can one do better?

Comment: I don't know. Geometrically this amounts to finding a closed embedding $\mathbb{A}^n \amalg \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^l$, and it feels as if it should be possible to do it in $\max \{ n, m \} + 1$...

Comment: Ah, but that's a brilliant comment you wrote, dear  Zhen! From your idea it follows that  $A[x]\times A[y]$ is generated by just $\{(x,y), (0,1)\}$ since $(0,y)=(x,y).(0,1),(x,0)=(x,y)-(0,y)$ and $(1,0)=(1,1)-(0,1)$.